# How to edit a variable in html file through VB 6

Tags: vb6

I am using google earth api, just want to change the variable in an html file that stores the latitude and longitude values.
Please help!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of latitude and longitude of the html page you can use webbrowser control.This will allow you to set value and access the page from your program code.